# In Java: Assigning a value in an array to a variable outside of an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

EDITED QUESTION FOR CLARITY:

> Assume that an array of int named a has been declared with 12
>   elements. The integer  variable  k holds a value between  0 and 6.
>   Assign 15 to the array element whose index is k.

Currently I did something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    if(w[i] == k) {
      w[i] = k;
}
```

}

Is my mode of thinking wrong?

EDIT:

This isn't homework. It's from my CS textbook practice exercises. I'm currently on break and have no teacher to ask. Sorry if it seems like I'm asking for homework help - that is not my intention. Just trying to understand, but this book isn't the most comprehensible thing I've read.

Comment: This seems like homework, ask your teacher or TA.  Yes, I think your thinking is wrong: the assignment said to "assign" not "insert".  But better confirm with the teacher/TA.

Comment: `index` means the part inside `[]`.  So if the instructions are "Assign 15 to the array element whose index is k", it basically means `arr[k] = 15;`.

Comment: @markspace This isn't homework. It's from my CS textbook practice exercises. I'm currently on break and have no teacher to ask. Sorry if it seems like I'm asking for homework help - that is not my intention.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for clearing that up. Sorry if I'm being a nuisance to this forum. I just assumed questions like this wouldn't be berated if they came from a book. By the way I would accept what you said as the answer, but I don't know how to do that from a direct reply.

Comment: You can't accept a comment as an answer.  I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Index" means the part inside `[]`. So if the instructions are "Assign 15 to the array element whose index is k", it basically means `arr[k] = 15;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your exercise question demand this check when it says "The integer variable k holds a value between 0 and 6"

```
if(i == k)
```

instead of

```
if(w[i] == k)
```

Hope you can understand it now.

Infact you don't need a loop at all, just do

```
arr[k] = valueToSet
```

Comment: Why do the loop and test at all?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just `a[k] = 15;`? The description says to directly assign 15 to the index `k`, it says nothing about the previous value at that index or that you should search for an element with the value `k`.

Comment: Yea basically that's what it is. But in my textbook the question - are supposed to - relate to the mini section before it. I didn't think it would be this simple. I feel dumb; guess I deserved the down-vote.